# Django2 AttributeError in urls.py

Tags: django, python-3.x

I'm getting started with Django but I'm stuck with an error while trying to execute `python3 manage.py runserver` .

> fmlg-backend/fmlg/urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from django.conf.urls import url
from core import views as coreviews

urlpatterns = ['',
    url(r'^$', coreviews.home), 
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls)
]
```

> fmlg-backend/core/views/views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render

def home(request):
    return render(request, 'core/home.html')
```

`python3 manage.py runserver` outputs :

```
 File "/home/florian/Workspace/project/fmlg-backend/fmlg/urls.py", line 22, in <module>
    url(r'^$', coreviews.home), 
AttributeError: module 'core.views' has no attribute 'home'
```

What am I missing here ?

Comment: You wrote your `views.py` in a separate `views` directory?

Comment: Yes I did that ! That wasn't the best idea apparently :), thank you for your answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Django's default file structure

I think to solve the problem fundamentally, you should **move your `views.py` file from `core/views/` to `core/`**. So no specific `views` directory. This is usually how a Django project is structured.

The reason is that now your `from core import views as coreviews` will *not* import the `views.py`, but the "*implicit*" module you have constructed with the `views` directory. As a result that module has a submodule named `views` that corresponds to the `views.py` module.

## Workaround: fixing the import

Alternatively, if you for example want to structure the views in separte files, you can fix the importing by writing:

```
from core.views import views as coreviews
```

But I would not advise that, since typically it is better to follow the structure of Django. Not only is it cleaner, and thus easier for another programmer to understand what is going on, but introducing your own file structure can create some trouble, since Django typically has a certain order in which it loads files to ensure that if you follow the structure, all elements that should be loaded, are loaded.

Comment: I think you can remove the workaround part, architecture of a project is important, I misunderstood it. In my `project` folder, I have `project/fmlg-backend` and `project/fmlg-frontend` (which is the angular part), is it correct to structure it like that ?